# Isn't it an evolutionary disadvantage to have a single organ perform so many essential functions?

Tags: human-evolution, liver

This is in reference to the human liver, responsible for not only the production of bile, but also the filtration of blood, metabolization of drugs, detoxification and so on. Liver failure is often synonymous with death. So how exactly did the liver come to perform so many essential functions, with no backup whatsoever?

Comment: While the liver is vital, I don't know why you consider it more of an evolutionary failure than many other organs. One would die without a working heart (heart failure), kidney, gastrointestinal tract, brain, lungs, etc. Maybe you can clarify your question a bit. Also, metabolism of drugs/detoxification are basically the same thing, and filtration of blood also occurs in the spleen (its major function). Thanks.

Comment: The brain performs many essential functions, although it's more like a "division of labour" type of grouping, like in a factory where everything happens in specific rooms... we could have many small livers and brains and gonads all around the body, although evolution has decided to group everything together pretty much since the early bilateral animals. What is weird is that the skeletomuscular components of arthropods and vertebrates are totally symmetrical, and the rest is totally assymetrical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but splitting it up into multiple organs is **also** a disadvantage, becasue you have to grow and upkeep said organs. every solution has its pros and cons that have to balanced.  Most of evolution is lesser of two evils compromises, kluges, or "good enough" solutions.